# Get data in Angular Service and pass it through to another controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I dont't know if this is the right way to tackle the issue im trying to solve, if you have a better idea or maby a more efficient way to do this Im all open for things :). I know I could do this also with broadcasting the value but I wanna use the service for changing and modify data based on the values it gets. I kinda simplified it only hoping it already would work.

So what is happening, I send a value on a click to the Service with:

```
$scope.newName = function(name) {
    nameService.newName(name);
};
```

Than receive the value into my service and try to send it to another controller with:

```
    var placeHolderName = 'anonymouse';
    var name = [];

    return {
        newName: function (repsonse) {
            placeHolderName = 'noAnonymouse'
            name = 'hi new' + repsonse;
        },

        getNewName: function() {

            if (placeHolderName === 'anonymouse') {
                return placeHolderName;
            }
            else {
                return name;
            }
        }
    };
```

But as you can see if there is no value passed in yet it just contains the 'anonymouse' name once there is a new value passed there is no need for the placeholder variable anymore.

and trying to update the 'anonymouse' name once there is a new value passed in through the service and it updates the $scope with the new value.
Im fetching it with:

```
$scope.name = nameService.getNewName();

$scope.$watch('name', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log(newValue, oldValue);
});
```

It sadly doesn't work the way I try to use it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer based on codepen:

Instead of watching `name`, you should watch for changes to `service.getName`

```js
var app = angular.module('test', []);

app.controller('sendController', function($scope, service) {
  $scope.newName = function(name) {
    service.setName(name);
  };
});

app.controller('getController', function($scope, service) {
  $scope.name = service.getName();
  $scope.$watch(service.getName, function(newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.name = newValue;
  });
});

app.factory('service', function() {
  var name = 'anonymouse';
  return {
    setName: function(newName) {
      name = newName
    },
    getName: function() {
      return (name === 'anonymouse') ? name : 'hi new' + name;
    }
  }
});
var el = document.getElementById('container');
angular.bootstrap(el, ['test']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div ng-controller="sendController">
    <button ng-click="newName('bob')">Bob</button>
    <button ng-click="newName('Dennis')">Dennis</button>
  </div>

  <div ng-controller="getController">
    {{ name }}
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also remove the `$scope.$watch` and do `$scope.name = service.getName;` along with updating the expression to `{{ name() }}`

---

If I understood correctly you can just do this:

```
  var name = 'Anonymous';
  return {
   setName: function(newName) {
     name = newName
   },
   getName: function() {
     return (name === 'Anonymous') ? name : 'hi new' + name;
  };
```

Comment: Found the solution had to recall the function in the controller where I wanna get the data, pretty stupid of mee but thanks for the part I used it and is way better than what I had thanks :)!

Comment: @Dennis see updated ans anyway.. :) some things in code pen as well as stack snippet is blocked in my network  so had to recreate things in jsfiddle

Comment: Didn't know you can just watch a function, learning that today. You'r is more efficient than mine. But may I ask a question why use a factory instead of just a service?

Comment: @Dennis service implementation  will look like [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0pc7ndb7/1/), also notice the update removing `$watch`

Comment: They both do the trick, what do you prefer using the watch or just like this. Im full of questions what is better to use for future parts im working on to make it better.

Comment: @T J When I log my the $scope.name in the get controller I get the function instead of the value, how's that :O?

Comment: @Dennis becuase `$scope.name = service.getName;` service.getName is function right..? You're seeing it. in the expression we're calling this function `{{ name() }}` and printing the value.

Comment: @Dennis as far as I know, angular has something like digest cycle, which happens few times every second. All expressions and things will be evaluated during it. If you have `{{ name() }}`, `service.getName` will be invoked every digest cycle. if you do `$scope.$watch(service.getName)`, you're telling the digest cycle to evaluate `service.getName every` cycle. both seem to be similar.(will invoke `service.getName` equal number of times). at least that's my understanding